# Disable Email Sending by Authenticated Users?

Tags: email, permissions

Running 5.3 on Drupal 7.

Is there any built in way to disable the ability for authenticated users to send an email?

Currently they can only view their own contact, but the action menu still has an option to send an email. Supposedly the permission is tied in with the "View All Contacts" permission, however that does not block them from sending an email.

Comment: Do you mean users were able to send emails even after removing `view all contacts` permission?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. They are limited to sending it to their contact, but we see potential security issues with that.